# Hosting a java servlet on a Tomcat Server

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, servlets

I have written a JAVA servlet that implements the "Facebook Connect" feature. I have installed Tomcat on my laptop locally and ca run it successfully.

I want to host the servlet now on a Tomcat Server, so that people from outside can log in and provide their Facebook data through the servlet.

How do I do this? Which Tomcat server hosting should I purchase from the web? What steps would be involved in getting this done? Any tutorials / references available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well seems you are looking for Hosting Solution, To host a website you need following things
1. Domain Name 
2. Application Server/Web Server (eg. Was/Tomcat/Weblogic)

If you want to host your website from your own computer , you will need a Real / Static Ip , which can be accessed from any where in the world, ask your ISP for REAL/STATIC ip and then map your domain to this ip , once propagated , users will be able to see the website , otherwise they can use this real ip to access .

Alternatively , to save yourself the headache of running a machine 24*7 , you can rent out some of the servers from Hosting providers and then deploy your application there saving the pain.

Comment: means no need to registration of Domain name and buy Hosting, if i know Static IP of my Internet connection. ? if so thats wonderfull.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some Google. There are various hosting service providers which offers Private and Shared hosting. Private Tomcat hosting will cost you more but at the same will give you more control where as shared tomcat will be at lower cost. So, It totally depends on your requirement.

You also have to purchase a domain name.
The hosting service provider will give you support on how to deploy. Generally you need to provide  `.war` file to service provider.

Comment: Is "doing some Google" a euphemism for something illegal?  :-)